# Trying to find the std of an array result in fault

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a bunch of files of the following order (tab separated):

```
h   local   average
1   4654    4654
2   5564    5564
3   6846    6846
... ...     ...
```

I read the file in a loop (attached below) and store them in a two dimensional list. I then convert the list to array and apply std to it. This results with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plot2.py", line 56, in <module>
    e0028 = np.std(ar, axis=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 2467, in std
    return std(axis, dtype, out, ddof)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'float'
```

Which baffles me. I tried to find an element in the array which is not float and nothing popped.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import fabs, sqrt, pow, pi

h0028 = []  
p0028 = []

headLines = 2

fig=plt.figure()  
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)  
for i in range (0,24):  

    n = 0  
    j = i + 560  
    p = []  
    f = open('0028/'+str(j)+'.0028/ionsDist.dat')  
    for line in f:  
        if n < headLines:  
            n += 1  
            continue  
        words = line.split()  
        p.append (float(words[1]))  
        if i == 0:  
            h0028.append (fabs(int(words[0])))  
        n += 1  
    print (n)  
    p0028.append(p)  
    f.close()  

ar = np.array(p0028)  
for a in ar:  
    for b in a:  
        if not isinstance(b,float):  
            print type(a)  

e0028 = np.std(ar, axis=0)  
p0028 = np.mean(ar, axis=0)  
h0028 = np.array(h0028)/10 -2.6  
p0028 /= max(p0028)  
e0028 /= (sum(p0028)*sqrt(23))  

ax1.errorbar(h0028 , p0028, yerr=e0028, color = 'red')  
ax1.set_xlim(-0.1,10)  

plt.show()  
plt.savefig('plot2.png', format='png')
```

Comment: what does `ar` look like? I tried to duplicate your results, but everything seems to work fine for me?

Comment: @JoelCornett I think that the problem is with the length of the files. Not all the files are of the same length

Comment: You can compute std for each of the column vectors individually. That might fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I can't figure out, why your code does not work, but maybe this will help you.
You can read the file like this:

```
    >>>a = np.loadtxt("p0028.csv",dtype="float",skiprows = 1)
    >>> a
    array([[  1.00000000e+00,   4.65400000e+03,   4.65400000e+03],
    [  2.00000000e+00,   5.56400000e+03,   5.56400000e+03],
    [  3.00000000e+00,   6.84600000e+03,   6.84600000e+03]])
```

Now you can get the std of e.g. the column local like this:

```
    >>>a_std = np.std(a[:1])
    2193.4452352406706
```

When you loop over several files, you can use the vstack method to collect the data together, that way you do not depend on the number of rows in the file:

```
    >>>a = np.loadtxt("p0028.csv",dtype="float",skiprows = 1)
    >>> a
    array([[  1.00000000e+00,   4.65400000e+03,   4.65400000e+03],
    [  2.00000000e+00,   5.56400000e+03,   5.56400000e+03],
    [  3.00000000e+00,   6.84600000e+03,   6.84600000e+03]])
    >>>b = np.loadtxt("p0028.csv",dtype="float",skiprows = 1)
    >>> np.vstack((a,b))
    array([[   1, 4654, 4654],
    [   2, 5564, 5564],
    [   3, 6846, 6846],
    [   1, 4654, 4654],
    [   2, 5564, 5564],
    [   3, 6846, 6846]])
```

Comment: I think I know the problem. The files are not all of the same length. Is there a simple way to add zeros at the ends?

Comment: i think that adding zeros will result in a wrong computation of the std

Comment: I tried this. The code run. I don't really care about the tail so the std doesn't really matter

Answer (score 1):

I have found the error, my file were not all of the same length. This caused a situation where  I accessed empty element. I have added a loop that add zeros at the end of each list till I get the same length. Schuh, noted that adding zero at the end might result in getting wrong std. This is not the case in my data but this should be noted.